# Total Row Count in sql query---sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, rowcount

My query is as follows

```
BEGIN

    WITH MyCTE
    AS (
        SELECT T.MusicAlbumTitle
            ,D.musicTitle
            ,D.mVideoID
            ,D.musicFileName
            ,T.ReleaseDate AS ReleasedDate
            ,D.MusicLength
            ,D.musicSinger
            ,D.MusicVideoID
            ,D.ExternalLink             
            ,D.CoverImg             
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY D.MusicVideoID ORDER BY D.mVideoID
                ) AS row_num
        FROM dbo.Music_Video T
        JOIN dbo.Music_Video_Details D ON T.MusicVideoID = D.MusicVideoID
        WHERE T.PortalID = @PortalID
            AND T.CultureCode = @CultureCode
            AND T.ComingSoon <> 1
        GROUP BY T.MusicAlbumTitle
            ,D.musicTitle
            ,D.mVideoID
            ,T.ReleaseDate
            ,D.musicFileName
            ,D.MusicLength
            ,D.musicSinger
            ,D.MusicVideoID
            ,D.ExternalLink
            ,D.CoverImg
        )   
    SELECT a.mVideoID
        ,a.MusicVideoID
        ,a.musicFileName            
        ,a.MusicAlbumTitle
        ,a.ReleasedDate
        ,a.row_num
        ,a.CoverImg
        ,a.ExternalLink         
        ,a.musicTitle
        ,a.MusicLength                  
    FROM MyCTE a            
    WHERE row_num = 1
    ORDER BY MusicVideoID DESC
END
```

I need to achieve total row count from last select statement.
which mean total row count that is being selected.

or any idea that might be use in this condition

How can i do this ..

Comment: Use `Select @@RowCount` it should return the number of rows returned from last statement

Answer (score 13):

Please add `COUNT(*) OVER()` in your select, which returns total rows selected as a new column.
Ex:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    COUNT(*) OVER() AS [Total_Rows] 
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, you need to add the count to the CTE, not the outer query.  The outer select is returning only one row, so the count would always be one.

The CTE should start:

```
WITH MyCTE
AS (
    SELECT T.MusicAlbumTitle
        ,D.musicTitle
        ,D.mVideoID
        ,D.musicFileName
        ,T.ReleaseDate AS ReleasedDate
        ,D.MusicLength
        ,D.musicSinger
        ,D.MusicVideoID
        ,D.ExternalLink             
        ,D.CoverImg             
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY D.MusicVideoID ORDER BY D.mVideoID
            ) AS row_num,
        COUNT(*) over () as total_count
```